# xamarin forms map's marker click event

Tags: google-maps, xamarin.forms, google-maps-markers

I have a map with a single pin on it. as follows:

```
var map = new Map()
                {
                    IsShowingUser = true,
                    HeightRequest = 100,
                    WidthRequest = 960,
                    VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand
                };
```

and the pin location and label as follows:

```
var pin1 = new Pin();
pin1.Type = PinType.Place;
pin1.Position = position;
pin1.Label = "Ticket Number: " + Cache.Instance.Ticket.TicketNumber;
```

clicked event:

```
pin1.Clicked += delegate
{
    uri = new Uri("http://maps.google.com/maps?daddr=" + position.Latitude + "," + position.Longitude);
    Device.OpenUri(uri);
}
```

map loading:

```
var stack = new StackLayout { Spacing = 00 };
        stack.Children.Add(map); 
        Content = stack;
```

when clicking on the pin marker, it opens an info window and clicking on the window and clicked event code triggers. It there any way to not show the info window and the event triggers as soon as I click on the marker?

Thanks

Comment: does this the trick ? :  `void Map_PinClicked(object sender, PinClickedEventArgs e) 
 { 
     e.Handled = true;
 }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Map_PinClicked` to handle the `PinClick` event, If you set `e.Handled = true`, then Pin selection doesn't work automatically. All pin selection operations are delegated to you.

In the Page:

```
    map.PinClicked += Map_PinClicked;

    // Selected Pin changed
    map.SelectedPinChanged += SelectedPin_Changed;

    map.InfoWindowClicked += InfoWindow_Clicked;

    map.InfoWindowLongClicked += InfoWindow_LongClicked;
```

And then clickEvent:

```
    void Map_PinClicked(object sender, PinClickedEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Handled = true;

        uri = new Uri("http://maps.google.com/maps?daddr=" + position.Latitude + "," + position.Longitude);
        Device.OpenUri(uri);

    }
```

You can have a look at [here](https://github.com/amay077/Xamarin.Forms.GoogleMaps/blob/master/XFGoogleMapSample/XFGoogleMapSample/PinsPage.xaml.cs) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Currently with Xamarin.Forms 5, PinClicked event is designated as obsolete. Same goes for Device.OpenUri.
One can use `pin1.MarkerClicked += Pin_Clicked;` instead.
You can prevent the Info window from opening by setting the EventArgs's `HideInfoWindow` property to true.
[docs.microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/map/pins)

```
 private async void Pin_Clicked(object sender, PinClickedEventArgs e)
 {
        try
        {
            e.HideInfoWindow = true;
            var pin = sender as Pin;
            var uri = new Uri("http://maps.google.com/maps?daddr=" + pin.Position.Latitude + "," + pin.Position.Longitude);
            Launcher.OpenAsync(uri);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
           //log error
        }
}
```